# Opções de Sinalização de Pergunta Duplicada

Tags: suporte, status-intencional, moderação

[Essa questão](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/2208/como-faco-para-ler-o-registro-das-chamadas-recebidas-e-efetuadas-no-iphone-utili/2379#2379) foi marcada como duplicada, na página de moderação, tenho a seguinte mensagem:

> respostas duplicadas (auto):
>
> Ler registro de histórico de SMS no iPhone usando Xamarin

Creio que o mesmo foi marcado de forma automática pelo Site, eu concordo que é duplicada, porem quando vou sinalizar, só tenho essas opções:
[image: opcoes de moderacao]

Nenhuma dessas indica "duplicada", como devo proceder? é erro do site?

Answer (score 2):

Esse tipo de sinalizador automático deve ser deixado para os moderadores tratarem. O que você pode fazer para ajudá-los é, dependendo do que achar do caso:

- Sinalizar o próprio sinalizador como inválido

ou

- Acrescentar um sinalizador do tipo "outro", com informações adicionais que julgar úteis para os moderadores tomarem sua decisão.

Note que o sinalizador não está tratando de uma *pergunta* duplicada, e sim de uma *resposta* que o sistema considerou duplicada. Isso não é necessariamente um problema. Neste caso não é, as respostas repetem um *boilerplate* mas são um pouco diferentes (menos do que seria necessário para o sistema não estranhar). São mesmo duas respostas distintas para dois problemas distintos.

Em casos em que uma resposta é copiada várias vezes para várias perguntas, um moderador pode optar por excluir uma ou mais das duplicatas – especialmente se for spam, ou não for uma resposta exata à pergunta onde foi postada.

Comment: seria o caso de responder como "outro" e deixar o comentário?

Comment: Se você achar que é o caso, pode sim fazer isso. Mas o que você diria no comentário? Eu acho que esse aí é um caso de flag inválido, que o moderador deve simplesmente dispensar.